# Create a pivot table with ORM Django

Tags: django

I'm working on Django project. This is my model.

[image]

From that model i would like to display a pivot table, like the one below.
I want to do a pivot table with Django ORM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL this would be `select week, categorie, count(*) from MyModel group by week, categorie`. The Django ORM uses [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) for that type of query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package, [django-pivot](https://pypi.org/project/django-pivot/) that does exactly this.